# SP13: Checked Out Document Items Not Visible

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions, check-in

I ran across something that I have nevertheless experienced using a document library.   Normally in a document library if a document is checked out the document is still visible on the list, however, the end-user will not be able to make any changes unless checked back in.  However, I come across where documents are checked out, however, their not visible on the list until checked in. Has anyone ever notice this?  Is there a setting that needs to be changed?  I checked to make sure there were no filters.  Also, grouping not turned on and the style is default.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default for items that have NEVER been checked in. There happens when someone uploads an item without filling in required metadata (usually through windows explorer)

There is a view for administrators inside the library settings area specifically to locate these items.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  If I use the admin checked out page located inside the library settings if the enduser made changes will be the changes be lost?  Thanks!

Comment: If you take ownership and check them in, no. If you delete them, obviously yes.